# Is there a command to generate all .mo files from multiple .po files?

Tags: internationalization, gettext, po, mo, msgfmt

I have multiple .po files in a standard directory structure of GNU gettext:

```
locales/
├── en_US
│   └── LC_MESSAGES
│       └── myapp.po
└── zh_TW
    └── LC_MESSAGES
        └── myapp.po
```

I knew that I could write a script that uses `msgfmt` to generate .mo files from these .po files. Something like:

```sh
# generate-mo-files.sh

for PO_FILE in locales/*/LC_MESSAGES/*.po
do
    MO_FILE="${PO_FILE/.po/.mo}"
    msgfmt -o "$MO_FILE" "$PO_FILE"
done
```

However, writing this script for each project I work on is a bit tedious. Is there a ready-made script for such use case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU autotools, you can use the script `gettextize` to prepare your project for gettext. Other build systems have similar special tools.

Otherwise, your little script is exactly the right solution.